# python networkx making nodes that are integers unique

Tags: python, unique, nodes, networkx

I'm trying to work through Project Euler [Problem 18](http://projecteuler.net/problem=18), which is finding the maximum value possible while going from top to bottom in a triangle of numbers, and you can only go through adjacent numbers on the row below. To do this I'm making a directed graph in network, then I'll do a topo sort on it and do a largest path algo. 
The problem I've run into is that some of the integers repeat throughout the triangle of numbers, so the computer thinks that there are edges between them when there shouldn't be.
Here is the triangle of numbers that I put into a .txt file.

```
75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23
```

Here is the code I made.

```
import networkx as nx

digraph = nx.DiGraph()

def convert_to_list(string):
    """
    Converts a string with newlines to a list of lists,
    where each list is delimited by the newlines
    and the \n is removed.
    """

    split_string = string.split('\n')
    outer_list = [[] for x in xrange(0,len(split_string))]

    for i in range (len(split_string)):
        line = split_string[i].split(' ')
        for number in line:
            outer_list[i].append(int(number))
    return outer_list

def extract_data(file_name="paths1.txt"):
    """
    Takes a file that contains a triangle of numbers
    and constructs a set of nodes and edges that satisfies
    the constraints of the Maximum path sum I and II
    on Project Euler
    """
    text_file = open(file_name, 'r')
    contents = text_file.read()
    #data_list is a list of lists, where each list is a row
    #in the triangle
    data_list = convert_to_list(contents)

    #Add all the nodes to the graph
    for row in data_list:
        for item in row:
            digraph.add_node(item)

    #Add all the edges to the graph
    for row_number in range(0, len(data_list)-1):
        for item_number in range(len(data_list[row_number])):
            digraph.add_edge(data_list[row_number][item_number],data_list[row_number+1][item_number])
            digraph.add_edge(data_list[row_number][item_number],data_list[row_number+1][item_number+1])
digraph_topo = nx.topological_sort(digraph)
extract_data()
```

**My question again:** How do I make these int nodes unique so the computer can tell the difference between the 75 on row 0 and the 75 on row 5 for example??
Thank you for any reply.

Comment: Hint: work bottom up - you don't need a graph

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants to do some graphs stuff while doing this, perhaps?

Comment: I thought graphs would be the way to go. Even if it isn't , I'd still like to know how to make nodes with the same value unique if I ever need to use graphs again in the future.

Comment: @user2980081 nodes just need to be unique objects... How you do that for your graph to work is up to you... a unique counter and decorate the edges with the value etc...

Comment: NetworkX is reading those integers, and when an integer is already present, it skips it. To get around this, in my answer below, I chose to enumerate the integers in a list so that I could make each one unique. You can chose to add 'uniqueness' to each integer in your own favourite way.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please "accept" it by clicking on the check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to passing in each item, I would suggest passing in an enumerated list of those items of some sort. Here's how I might do it, using the data you provided:

```
In [4]: df = pd.read_csv('triangle.csv', header=None)

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
0   75 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   95  64 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   17  47  82 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   18  35  87  10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   20   4  82  47  65 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   19   1  23  75   3  34 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   88   2  77  73   7  63  67 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   99  65   4  28   6  16  70  92 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   41  41  26  56  83  40  80  70  33 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   41  48  72  33  47  32  37  16  94  29 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
10  53  71  44  65  25  43  91  52  97  51  14 NaN NaN NaN NaN
11  70  11  33  28  77  73  17  78  39  68  17  57 NaN NaN NaN
12  91  71  52  38  17  14  91  43  58  50  27  29  48 NaN NaN
13  63  66   4  68  89  53  67  30  73  16  69  87  40  31 NaN
14   4  62  98  27  23   9  70  98  73  93  38  53  60   4  23

In [24]: for row in df.iterrows():
   ....:     for item in row[1]:
   ....:         if np.isnan(item) == False:
   ....:             l.append((n, item))
   ....:             n += 1


In [26]: import networkx as nx

In [27]: G = nx.Graph()

In [28]: G.add_nodes_from(l)

In [29]: G.nodes()
Out[29]: 
[(113, 73.0),
 (74, 39.0),
 (64, 51.0),
 (111, 70.0),
 (72, 17.0),
 (69, 28.0),
 (102, 87.0),
 (46, 48.0),
 (118, 4.0),
 (105, 4.0),
 (92, 66.0),
 (55, 53.0),
 (19, 3.0),
 (17, 23.0),
 (90, 48.0),
 (18, 75.0),
 (27, 67.0),
 (37, 41.0),
 (8, 87.0),
 (59, 25.0),
 (43, 70.0), etc......
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For your question on how to make the nodes unique: There's no need for the node's name to be the value.  Networkx allows lots of things as nodes (anything hashable).  So you could for example have a class defined and each node is an element of that class with node.value() giving the actual numerical value.

In this case, a decent option would be to note that each is in row i and column j, with value v.  So you could add nodes as G.add_node((i,j))  and then have a separate dict with val[(i,j)] to be the actual value of the node.